# created file path but the photo wont save I keep getting the catch

Tags: java, android

```
 shareButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share_btn);

    ScreenShotHold = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    bytearrayoutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View OnclickView) {

            view = OnclickView.getRootView();

            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();

            ScreenShotHold.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            String foldername = "WhatsThis";
            mkFolder(foldername);


            try
            {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,8000,out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                Log.d("WhatsThisApp","Screenshot Saved!");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("WhatsThisApp","Screenshot not Saved!");
            }

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                    + "/drawable/" + "ic_launcher");
            sharingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
            sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
        }
    });

}


public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
public int mkFolder(String folderName){ // make a folder under Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
        Log.d("myAppName", "Error: external storage is unavailable");
        return 0;
    }
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        Log.d("myAppName", "Error: external storage is read only.");
        return 0;
    }
    Log.d("myAppName", "External storage is not read only or unavailable");

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, // request permission when it is not granted.
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d("myAppName", "permission:WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: NOT granted!");
        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),folderName);
    int result = 0;
    if (folder.exists()) {
        Log.d("myAppName","folder exist:"+folder.toString());
        result = 2; // folder exist
    }else{
        try {
            if (folder.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("myAppName", "folder created:" + folder.toString());
                result = 1; // folder created
            } else {
                Log.d("myAppName", "creat folder fails:" + folder.toString());
                result = 0; // creat folder fails
            }
        }catch (Exception ecp){
            ecp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

I am trying to save the screenshot on android so that it will appear in the phones photo gallery. The file path creates just fine, but the try/catch statement to save the screenshot always ends with a file not saved exemption. I am using a Log.d to return what is happening in the code. I tried to post a screenshot of the Logcat, but apparently I don't have enough reputation to do such things...

I am using a physical device to test the application. I also requested the write to external media in the manifest. I am kinda stuck at the moment.

UPDATE:

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View OnclickView) {

            view = OnclickView.getRootView();

            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();

           // ScreenShotHold.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            String foldername = "WhatsThis";

            mkFolder(foldername);

            File file = mkFolder(foldername);


            try
            {
                file.createNewFile();
                fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fileoutputstream.write(bytearrayoutputstream.toByteArray());
                fileoutputstream.close();
                Log.d("WhatsThisApp","Screenshot Saved!");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("WhatsThisApp","Screenshot not Saved!");
            }

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                    + "/drawable/" + "ic_launcher");
            sharingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
            sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
        }
    });

}


public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
public File mkFolder(String folderName){ // make a folder under Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    int result = 0;
    if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
        Log.d("myAppName", "Error: external storage is unavailable");
        result = 0;
    }
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        Log.d("myAppName", "Error: external storage is read only.");
        result = 0;
    }
    Log.d("myAppName", "External storage is not read only or unavailable");


    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),folderName);

    if (folder.exists()) {
        Log.d("myAppName","folder exist:"+folder.toString());
        result = 2; // folder exist
    }else{
        try {
            if (folder.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("myAppName", "folder created:" + folder.toString());
                result = 1; // folder created
            } else {
                Log.d("myAppName", "creat folder fails:" + folder.toString());
                result = 0; // creat folder fails
            }
        }catch (Exception ecp){
            ecp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return folder;
}
```

Ok... I am still getting the log "saying screenshot not saved!"
App permissions for storage was enabled.

Here are my LOGS

```
11-26 16:56:13.527 28399-28454/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-26 16:56:13.527 28399-28454/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
11-26 16:56:13.541 28399-28449/? W/AnalyticsUserIDStore: initStore should have been called before calling setUserID
11-26 16:56:16.580 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-26 16:56:16.662 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 I/WhatsThisAppLogging: In the onCreate() method of the WhatsThisAPPActivity Class
11-26 16:56:16.662 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 D/MainActivity: onCreate(Bundle) called
11-26 16:56:16.664 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 D/WhatsThisAppLogging: onStart() called
11-26 16:56:16.666 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 D/WhatsThisAppLogging: onResume() called
11-26 16:56:28.119 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 D/myAppName: External storage is not read only or unavailable
11-26 16:56:28.121 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 D/myAppName: folder exist:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/WhatsThis
11-26 16:56:28.127 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 D/myAppName: External storage is not read only or unavailable
11-26 16:56:28.129 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 D/myAppName: folder exist:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/WhatsThis
11-26 16:56:28.130 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/WhatsThis (Is a directory)
11-26 16:56:28.130 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
11-26 16:56:28.130 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
11-26 16:56:28.130 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
11-26 16:56:28.130 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/System.err:     at edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:185)
11-26 16:56:28.131 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)
11-26 16:56:28.131 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285)
11-26 16:56:28.131 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
11-26 16:56:28.131 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-26 16:56:28.131 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
11-26 16:56:28.131 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6154)
11-26 16:56:28.131 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-26 16:56:28.131 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-26 16:56:28.131 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
11-26 16:56:28.131 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 D/WhatsThisApp: Screenshot not Saved!
11-26 16:56:28.144 28399-28399/edu.selu.teamtron.whatsthis2 D/WhatsThisAppLogging: onPause() called
```

Comment: put the content of the logcat

Comment: What is the `Exception` thrown?

Comment: `new FileOutputStream(file);`. What is 'file'? And i see no connection with mkFolder(). And you are not checking the return value of mkFolder().

Comment: Dirty code while putting permission code in mkFolder(). Further you request permission and do not wait for a result. I do not understand this mess. You can so easily find correct code on internet and on stackiverflow.

Comment: Well, I am still learning the ends and outs of android development and at the same time trying to understand the android development documentation. So you are absolutely correct, I am not checking for the return value of the mkFolder() method. I will go ahead and implement that... and as for "file", that was a previous value that I had been using that no longer goes anywhere, which I never realized. So, I can see how this is dirty code. What value should go there? I was thinking more of the pathway. Also, should I not have this in a method, to begin with?

Comment: You should change the return type of mkFolder() to File. Then let it return 'folder' or 'null'. After the call construct File file using the folder.

Comment: @greenapps  Forgive my ignorance, but this is what I have after changing the return value of mkFolder() from int to File and returning folder. BTW.. I appreciate your help!                    

                File file = new File(folder);   //folder is giving me an error...

Comment: Dont put code in comments. Adapt the code in your post instead. We wanna see what you have now. Otherwise it is difficult talking. Take requesting for permisions out of mkFolder. Then go on your Android device to the Settings of your app and switch the toggle for Storage to ON.

Comment: @greenapps  So, I still can't get it to save the image. It only creates the path. See above logs and updated code. Thanks for the commenting tips.

Comment: You have not done what i asked for. `public int mkFolder`. I asked you to change that to `public File mkFolder`. Further you call mkFolder twice where you should only call it once. And only if the folder does not exist yet. Further you use the result of mkFolder to open a file output stream. But that will not work for a folder. File file should be a file. I see not even a file name. Please adapt your code and post here.

Comment: @greenapps I am getting lost because I did change that method from public int mkFolder to public File mkFolder... I had to because I changed the return value from an "int" to a "File".

Comment: What are you still messing around with int result in mkFolder? Do away with it. Just return `null' every time instead.

Comment: And you still call mkFolder twice.

Comment: And you still use the same File object for creating a directory and creating a file. That is the error message.

Comment: Ok, I think I may be catching on to what you are getting at... Let me play with it some and I will get back to you if I am still having trouble.